# Neo4j - complexity of search by indexed parameter

Tags: neo4j

I'm wondering what is the complexity of the following cypher query:

```
MATCH (i:Instance{id:{InstanceID}})
RETURN i
LIMIT 1
```

The "id" has unique constraint:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (i:Instance) ASSERT i.id IS UNIQUE;
```

How the search time is affected with a growing number of Instance nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the unique index this node lookup will be backed by an index (internally Lucene is used here). So it should be `O(log(n))`.

Comment: Even with the unique constraint? Seems like that should make it O(1), unless that's the cost of whatever plumbing code is working behind the scenes. Did they really not optimize this kind of lookup?

Comment: I'd be very interested how you'd implement a `O(1)` in this case.

Comment: Basing that purely on speculation of using a hash-based index in the case of properties with unique constraints, coupled with complete unfamiliarity with Lucene indexing or any other highly scalable indexing design. In other words, I'm out of my depth here, but still curious what the major barriers are to any potential optimization.